# ¿Como puedo importar una libreria externa en NetBeans?

Tags: java, ide, netbeans-11.3

[image: Aqui estan los paquetes de mi pryecto]

**Problema: no me deja añadir librerias externas(JARs), le doy clik derecho en donde dice "Java Dependencies" y no me aparece el menu, ademas cuando creo otro proyecto como java aplication solo me crea las carpetas que ven en la imagen y no me crea la carpeta libraries.**

Quisiera saber si hay alguna u otra forma de añadir librerias a mi proyecto que no sea la antes mencionada...

(**Version de NetBeans:** 11.3)

Comment: Yo le doy un +1 a la pregunta porque me parece útil, y en este caso no hay código que mostrar (no tendría sentido preguntar por código ya que es un problema técnico),  espero otros usuarios comprendan esto en vez de simplemente votar la pregunta negativamente por no contener codigo (en este caso que codigo podria mostrar el?)... sin embargo no se como ayudarte ya que la verdad no uso Java, pase por aquí por curiosidad, Haz intentado crear tu la carpeta libraries?

Comment: Encontré esta solución y me sirvió.
"El problema radica en el tipo de proyecto. El que creaste es uno Maven debes crear uno Ant. Dirígete a Nuevo proyecto y buscas donde dice Java with Ant Despues seleccionas Java Application. Hay ya te va a permitir agregar las librerías y te aparecerá la interfaz del proyecto como en la versión 8.2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola @JPprogramador te explico lo que sucede:

Netbeans 11+ genera por defecto los proyectos "Java Application" utilizando Maven , que es una tecnología que te ayuda con la gestión de dependencia y la construcción del proyecto, esto lo puedes ver porque en el logo de la taza del proyecto java aparece una pequeña `m` en la parte superior izquierda, por eso no puedes agregar librerías externas de forma manual ya que según la filosofía de Maven seria una mala práctica.

Para agregar librerías hay 2 opciones:

1. Buscar las dependencias en el [repositorio central de maven](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central) donde encontraras casi todas las librerías existentes en java, por ejemplo si quieres agregar la librería de conexión de base de datos para MySQL https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java, en la carpeta `Project Files` se encuentra el archivo `pom.xml` donde se gestionan las dependencias y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.20</version>
            </dependency>

      <!--aqui mas dependencias-->

        </dependencies>
```

Como puedes ver, debes de agregar dentro del nodo `project` el nodo `dependencies` y dentro cada dependencia de tu proyecto que busques en maven central, la dependencia se divide en:

**groupId:** representa el paquete de la dependencia con el que fue creado el proyecto, bajo este paquete pueden existir múltiples librerías.

**artifactId:** representa el nombre de la librería que utilizaras.

**version:** representa la versión de la librería a utilizar en maven central puedes ver todas las versiones disponibles.

Cuando guardes el cambio en el archivo `pom` netbeans ira a descargar la dependencia desde el repositorio central y te aparecerá la librearía en la carpeta `dependencies`.

2. La otra opción es que descargues he instales la librería manualmente con Maven, pero no profundizare en esta ocasión esa parte porque debes instalar maven para poder ejecutar los comandos desde la terminal.

Todas las librearía descargadas con maven las puede encontrar en una carpeta oculta dentro de tu usuario en la ruta %UserProfile%.m2\repository, si piensas entrar en el mundo de java es importante que te familiarices con Maven o Gladle que son los 2 proyecto de gestión y construcción de proyectos mas importantes.

Utilizar maven es muy importante porque permite que los equipos ya no tengan que preocuparse de las librerías en los proyecto, porque al importar el proyecto en otra pc maven se encargará de descargar las librerías que no estén disponible en tu ambiente loca para que tengas listo tu proyecto para ejecución, anteriormente existían problemas como por ejemplo: si trabajas en equipo tenías que compartir el proyecto junto con todas las librerías y si agregamos un anueva librería o cambiamos de versión a una mas reciente tenias que garantizar que cada miembro que trabaja en el proyecto  recibiera un a notificación para agregar la nueva librería o actualizar la versión de las que ya existieran.